# Ember upgrade Why can't the module be found

Tags: ember.js, frontend, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to upgrade my Ember project. Specifically, I want to upgrade `ember-auto-import` to version 2.x. However, this requires at least Ember 4.x. So, I upgraded every dependency in my `package.json` that is related to Ember itself (`ember-source`, `ember-data`, etc.). After upgrading everything, this is my [package.json](https://github.com/puzzle/cryptopus/blob/feature/665-frontend-upgrade/frontend/package.json).

However, as soon as I start the application, I encounter [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njkc0.png).

After some investigation, I realized that even though the required package is listed in the `package.json` of the dependency, it doesn't get downloaded inside the `node_modules` folder of the package. I attempted to import the missing package in the `package.json` of the application itself, but that didn't help. What I found is that if I remove the package that throws the error, another package throws a similar error. Therefore, I think it's not an error with the package itself, but rather an error with `ember-auto-import` or my configuration.

Does anybody know about this type of error and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you all please tell me what's wrong with this question instead of just downvote it?

Comment: Sorry for that, I don't know who's downvoting your question -- as your question is legit.

Maybe it's bots? idk. I wish I could, as a mod, report this behavior. ugh.

To help me better understand your situation, can you include the package.json and error text in the question? I'm having issues with the images, and I think text would be much easier to read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i had similar error before when i have upgraded ember-auto-import to version 2.., the problem was that i had index.html including only `app-vendor.js` and `app.vendor.css` but with ember-auto-import 2 it generate multi chunks files that need to be injected to index.html , this would be done automatically when you upgrade everything correctly, so i think your problem could be in your index.html,
check if chunks scripts are injected in index.html
if not add
`<auto-import-script entrypoint="app"></auto-import-script>`
to where you want the script to be placed

or create a new project with a recent version of ember with same name of your project and check the differences with your index.html